# Compare values of one Array and output

Tags: php, arrays, magento

i have an array that can contain the same value more than once. What I'm trying to find is a way to compare the values inside that array and output every value only once.

```
$_just_a_tier = array();

foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item){
// count all products

    $_tierprice = $this->getTierPrices($_item);
     foreach ($_tierprice as $_ay){                              
                $_tier = $_ay['price_qty'];                              
               // echo $_tier.' &#124; ';

                $_just_a_tier[] = $_tier;
      }
}

print_r($_just_a_tier);
```

this will output e.g. that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 36
    [1] => 50
    [2] => 72
    [3] => 108
    [4] => 110
    [5] => 120
    [6] => 144
    [7] => 180
    [8] => 360
    [9] => 540
    [10] => 960
    [11] => 20
    [12] => 30
    [13] => 36
    [14] => 72
    [15] => 108
    [16] => 144
    [17] => 180
    [18] => 360
    [19] => 540
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a built-in function in PHP called [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) that solves this problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at PHP's [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function?